# What's the point of cache clean _and_ invalidate in ARM Cortex processors?

Tags: caching, embedded, cpu-cache, cortex-m

What is the point of clean *and* invalidate for cache in ARM Cortex processors? Clean writes the cache contents to memory, and then invalidate guarantees that these just written contents are read again on next access?

I'm quite sure I'm missing something trivial here, as otherwise there wouldn't be a separate register in SCB to clean & invalidate. I've tried googling, reading [the ARM reference manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0013/d/Caches/Invalidating-and-cleaning-cache-memory) and so on, and I don't see anything pointing to different than what I wrote above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean commits the dirty cache to memory and marks it clean.

Invalidate removes those cached items from memory.

If they're re-accessed, yes, they'll be reloaded into the cache, but if not...well, now the cache is available for other things.

You usually use clean and invalidate on a buffer you've completed work on and no longer care about from the processor point of view.   A good example of this would be audio buffers being sent to a DMA fed I2S port or DAC device.

Comment: This cleared up the confusion I was having: I was just thinking of _correctness_ in terms of the cache, but while cleaning a DMA buffer is enough for that, doing clean and invalidate also frees up the cache space. Thanks!